# C - Scan matrix array and send it to a function?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make get_move() to either scan Player 1's or Player 2's move on a matrix with xy  coordinates.

get_move() is going to have two parameters. First one will be which of the two players is making the move (Player 1 or Player 2). The second parameter will be the move, which has to be an array.

The thing I don't understand is how I am supposed to scan the move from the main function and then send it as a parameter to get_move(). I mean it's get_move() that is going to scan the move, but one of the parameters in get_move() is going to be the scanned xy coordinate array?!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_move(int player, char input[])
{

    printf("Player %d, make your move: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &input[][]);

}



int main(void)
{

    int player = 1;

    get_move(player, ???); // I can't scan the coordinates and insert them as the second parameter, because the function is supposed to make the scan???

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: Consider checking the result: `if (2 != scanf("%d %d", &input[0], &input[1])) handle_error();`, or better yet, use `fgets()/sscanf()` combo.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for my careless.

Let's assuming that `input[0]` is x and `input[1]` is y.

so in the main function:

```
     int main(void)
     {
         int td[2], player = 1;

         get_move(player, td);

         return 0;
     }
```

the `get_move(int player, int* td)`:

```
     void get_move(int player,  int* td)
     {
          printf("player...%d\n", player);
          scanf("%d %d", &td[0], &td[1]);

          printf("x..%d\ny..%d\n", td[0], td[1]);
      }
```

---

1. U should define a struct, (Better data structure can reduce the complexity of your coding)

   ```
   struct tdim_corrdinate {
       int x;
       int y;
   };

   typedef struct tdim_corrdinate two_dim;
   ```
2. Now you can pass this struct to your function `get_move()`, for example:

   ```
   void get_move(int player, two_dim td)
   {
       printf("Player %d, make your move: ", player);
       scanf("%d %d", &td.x, &td.y); 
       // more operations.
   }

   int main(void)
   {
        int player = 1;

        two_dim td;
        get_move(player, td);

        return 0;
   }
   ```
3. for more, I think u should figure out parameter and argument (OR formal parameter and actual parameter).

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is that I must use an array to get the xy coordinates. I haven't been looking at struct yet and in this particular game I have to use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the sample code you have provided. Let's take a look at each of them, one at a time:

- Allocate a space to keep the player's moves. Since there are two players, and the move will be an (x, y) coordinate, you will need a 2x2 array. You also need to decide the data type for the array. Since there is information on the size of the play area, I have picked `int`.

```c
int input[2][2];
```

- Adjust the format string for `scanf` based on the data type of your input array. If you are using `int` as the data type, you can use `%d` as the format string in `scanf`. If you are using chars instead, use `%c` as the format string. Refer to [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) for more info on format strings.
- Pay attention to how to declare arrays and then how to use them. Note how I do not use empty brackets following the array `input` in `scanf`. Compare that to your `scanf` line. Empty brackets can be used in function signatures (such as `get_move(...)`) to pass an existing array to the function. In this case, when you want to tell `scanf` to put the x and y coordinates in the array, you need to pass two pointers to the scanf function. The `&` operator provides you a pointer to the variable it precedes. Here `input[0]` and `intput[1]` are the variables whose pointers we are interested in.

```c
scanf("%d %d", &input[0], &input[1]);
```

**Fixed Code**

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void get_move(int player, int input[]) {
        char temp = 0;

        printf("Player %i\'s move? ", player);
        scanf("%d %d", &input[0], &input[1]);

        // capture the user pressing the return key, which creates a newline
        scanf("%c", &temp);
    }

    int main() {
        int input[2][2];

        int i;                  // index into the player array

        // read players' moves
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            get_move(i, input[i]);
        }

        // print players' moves
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            printf("player %i: %d %d\n", i, input[i][0], input[i][1]);
        }
    }
```